# Building an nth order ODE in Maple (or Matlab)

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, systems-of-equations, maple

The question is simple: given a system of ODEs, how can one construct the equivalent nth order ODE in Maple? In my case I have

$$
\begin{cases}
y''(t)+x'(t)+x(t)=f(t)\\
y''(t)+z''(t)+z'(t)+z(t)=0\\
x(t)=y(t)+z(t)
\end{cases}
$$

and I would like to get a 4th order ODE in x(t) with the same solutions as the system above. Is there any Maple command to do this? (or maybe Matlab?)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
des:= {diff(y(t),t$2)+ diff(x(t),t) + x(t) = f(t), 
    diff(y(t),t$2) + diff(z(t),t$2) + diff(z(t),t) + z(t) = 0,
    x(t) = y(t) + z(t)};
DEtools[casesplit](des,[z(t),y(t),x(t)],arbitrary={f});
```

$$ \eqalign{\bigg[ z \left( t \right) & = x \left( t \right) +{\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t
}^{3}}}x \left( t \right) +{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t
 \right) -f \left( t \right)
\cr
y \left( t \right) &=-{\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x \left( t
 \right) -{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right) +f \left( t
 \right) 
\cr
{\frac {{\rm d}^{4}}{{\rm d}{t}^{4}}}x \left( t \right) &\left.= -2\,{\frac {
{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right) -2\,{\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right) +{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}f \left( t
 \right) -x \left( t \right) -{\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}x
 \left( t \right) +f \left( t \right) 
\right]
\cr
 \&where \;[]}
$$